# Neo4j: Issue updating from 2.0.1 to 2.1.1

Tags: neo4j

Right after updating Neo4j from 2.0.1 to 2.1.1, I got this error:

> Starting Neo4j Server failed: Startup failed due to preflight task
>   [class org.neo4j.server.preflight.PerformUpgradeIfNecessary]: Unable
>   to upgrade database

(Windows Vista x64)

Comment: 2.1.1 has some known issues. A 2.1.2 will be released in the very near future. When it's out retry migrating form 2.0.1 -> 2.1.2 and check if the issue vanishes.

Comment: I have the same error. Dowgraded to 2.0.3 (IMHO, it's stablest version today)

Comment: 2.1.2 doesn't seem to solve the issue. Same error.

Answer (score 1):

While store upgrades are not required for the 2.1 update, it may help if you make the following configuration changes.

In the neo4j.properties configuration file, uncomment the second line below.

```
# Enable this to be able to upgrade a store from an older version
#allow_store_upgrade=true
```

Make sure you backup your database folder before proceeding to restart the database.

Comment: Same result:  "Starting Neo4j Server failed: Startup failed due to preflight task [class org.neo4j.server.preflight.PerformUpgradeIfNecessary]: Unable to upgrade database"

Comment: Did you upgrade this store from 1.9.x previously? As Stefan said, 2.1.2 should fix this issue. Can you please IM me on Skype, kenny.bastani so we can work through the issue in the meantime. I'd like to understand if this is a Windows issue only.